# Unable to access page controls when changing a Xamarin.iOS controller from UIViewController into a PageRenderer

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am moving a Xamarin iOS project into Xamarin Forms, working in Visual Studio 2017.

In my iOS project i have a controller that  has its components (UIWebView, UIImageView among others) in a storyboard. I have changed so that my controller now inherit fom `PageRenderer` instead of `UIViewController` and i use `ExportRenderer` to reference it from within Forms and that part works just fine.

My issue is that the components that are used in my controller that are declared in the controller.designer.cs file are now all null when I try to use them in the controller.cs file, I guess I am missing some step to actually get the component instances set.

Any hint on what to try next would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you define a UI using a storyboard, when the system deserializes the XML the system takes care of creating new instances of all the objects you've defined and "wiring them together" in terms of adding them to the `UIViewController` or their parent `UIView` objects or what-have-you.

If you want to port from that model to building the UI in code, you have to recreate that process, instantiating the instances and building the view-controller and view hierarchies. (If you defined transitions and so forth in the storyboard, you'll have to programmatically instantiate and wire them together as well.)

PS: The Storyboard deserialization process uses constructors that take an `IntPtr`, while when you do it in code, you'll most likely use a default ctor. If there's any custom code inside your existing `IntPtr` ctors, you'll need to move that into the constructor you use.

Comment: Ok, I haved looked at this blogpost https://www.martinnorin.se/combining-xamarin-forms-with-ios-storyboard/ in which the author seem to have a solution but I cannot make it work, mainly because my ExportRenderer does not have the IntPtr constructor that you mention, do you know if there is a better way to instantiate the storyboard items?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're facing, but it's common for your custom class to have an `IntPtr` that calls the `base` constructor. That's common when using a custom class in conjunction with Storyboard/NIB deserialization.

Comment: `PageRenderer` which is my base now does not have a constructor that takes an `IntPtr` so I tried to set base.Handle = handle in the body of my Controllers constructor instead to pass intptr to my base.

This actually gives me a controller with instances of the objects but instead now I get a null reference exception thrown from `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.PageRenderer.ViewDidAppear (System.Boolean animated) [0x0001f] in D:\agent\_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderers\PageRenderer.cs:76`.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm flying a little too blind to suggest anything. Can you either this question or open a new one, showing some code?

Comment: Basically i have no code specific to the problem to post, I have tested a few different approaches but non have worked so far. I will look around for a working example of using a storyboard in forms and try to update my question if i can think of a good way to make it more clear. Thanks a lot for all your help so far!

Comment: About your suggestion "*to port from that model to building the UI in code, you have to recreate that process, instantiating the instances and building the view-controller and view hierarchies*"

Do you know of any example on how to actually do that in a `PageRenderer` that I could look into?